# Format Float to n decimal places

Tags: java, android, floating-point, numbers, format

I need to format a float to "n"decimal places.

was trying to BigDecimal, but the return value is not correct...

```
public static float Redondear(float pNumero, int pCantidadDecimales) {
    // the function is call with the values Redondear(625.3f, 2)
    BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(pNumero);
    value = value.setScale(pCantidadDecimales, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN); // here the value is correct (625.30)
    return value.floatValue(); // but here the values is 625.3
}
```

I need to return a float value with the number of decimal places that I specify.

I need `Float` value return not `Double`

.

Answer (score 593, accepted):

You may also pass the float value, and use:

`String.format("%.2f", floatValue);`

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

Comment: Please be carefull as String.format depend on your current Local configuration, you may not get a dot as a separator. Prefer using `String.format(java.util.Locale.US,"%.2f", floatValue);`

Comment: this answer gives a String value, not a Float value,  I don't think a good answer.

Comment: Why would you force a dot as separator?

Comment: @MarkBuikema I think there are cases where it would be absolutely necessary, such as when compiling document formats driven by standards, eg. PDF documents.

Comment: This answer does not create a float

Comment: When you try to contain this in a Float object, the precision will be the same as of float only(precision is up to 6 decimal places). For better precision, Double class can be used.

Answer (score 38):

Take a look at [DecimalFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).  You can easily use it to take a number and give it a set number of decimal places.

*Edit*: [Example](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/102.html)

Comment: +1. Here's the [Android-specific documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html),which should be essentially the same.

Comment: but I need the result is a float number, not a string.

Comment: Are you saying you want to round the float?  Normally the only time precision of a float matters is for display.

Comment: sorry, you're right, I was confused, just format the number when shown on screen, not before, that was my question, thank you very much, problem solved.

Comment: Of note, use of `DecimalFormat` constructor is discouraged, see my answer for a correct use of `NumberFormat`.

Answer (score 18):

Try this this helped me a lot

```
BigDecimal roundfinalPrice = new BigDecimal(5652.25622f).setScale(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

Result will be
roundfinalPrice --> 5652.26

Comment: This is more useful for those looking to round and do some further computations with it, otherwise, Arve's answer is probably best.

Comment: This works with GWT as well. String.format() - does not.

Answer (score 16):

Of note, use of `DecimalFormat` constructor is discouraged. The javadoc for this class states:

> In general, do not call the DecimalFormat constructors directly, since the NumberFormat factory methods may return subclasses other than DecimalFormat.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

So what you need to do is (for instance):

```
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
formatter.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP); 
Float formatedFloat = new Float(formatter.format(floatValue));
```

Comment: This is not working when (for example) floatValue = 8.499. It is giving 8.5.

Comment: @ShivakrishnaChippa: yes, because here we specify that we want 2 digits after the comma, and to do a up rounding. In that case, 8.499 is rounded to 8.5. If you want 8.499 to be display, simply set 3 as the maximum fraction digits.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a quick sample using the `DecimalFormat` class mentioned by Nick.

```
float f = 12.345f;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
System.out.println(df.format(f));
```

The output of the print statement will be 12.35. Notice that it will round it for you.

Comment: Of note, use of `DecimalFormat` constructor is discouraged, see my answer for a correct use of `NumberFormat`.

Answer (score 5):

Kinda surprised nobody's pointed out the direct way to do it, which is easy enough.

```
double roundToDecimalPlaces(double value, int decimalPlaces)
{
      double shift = Math.pow(10,decimalPlaces);
      return Math.round(value*shift)/shift;
}
```

Pretty sure this does not do half-even rounding though.

For what it's worth, half-even rounding is going to be chaotic and unpredictable any time you mix binary-based floating-point values with base-10 arithmetic. I'm pretty sure it cannot be done. The basic problem is that a value like 1.105 cannot be represented exactly in floating point. The floating point value is going to be something like 1.105000000000001, or 1.104999999999999. So any attempt to perform half-even rounding is going trip up on representational encoding errors.

IEEE floating point implementations will do half-rounding, but they do binary half-rounding, not decimal half-rounding. So you're probably ok

Comment: I've also used this method for a while, but I would think that `pow` is a too expensive operation to use for rounding?

Comment: Never optimize until you actually have a performance problem. More important to be right than fast. And I can't honestly imagine an application where performance of controlled rounding would be an issue, unless you were Visa or Mastercard (who would just throw more machines at it). And pow() is probably faster than round().

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for an answer to this question and later I developed a method! :) A fair warning, it's rounding up the value.

```
private float limitDigits(float number) {
    return Float.valueOf(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%.2f", number));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static double roundToDouble(float d, int decimalPlace) {
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(Float.toString(d));
        bd = bd.setScale(decimalPlace, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
        return bd.doubleValue();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a much less professional and much more expensive way but it should be easier to understand and more helpful for beginners.

```
public static float roundFloat(float F, int roundTo){

    String num = "#########.";

    for (int count = 0; count < roundTo; count++){
        num += "0";
    }

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(num);

    df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

    String S = df.format(F);
    F = Float.parseFloat(S);

    return F;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want ist

```
return value.toString();
```

and use the return value to display.

```
value.floatValue();
```

will always return 625.3 because its mainly used to calculate something.

Comment: but I need the result is a float number, not a string.

Comment: if you need a float to show it to the user, there may be something wrong with the design of the application. Usually the float is used to calculate and a string is used to show it to the user.

Comment: sorry, you're right, I was confused, just format the number when shown on screen, not before, that was my question, thank you very much, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Decimal format if you want to format number into a string, for example:

```
String a = "123455";
System.out.println(new 
DecimalFormat(".0").format(Float.valueOf(a)));
```

The output of this code will be:

123455.0

You can add more zeros to the decimal format, depends on the output that you want.

Comment: DecimalFormat#format takes a double, making the formatted float have more digits than a float can hold.