# How can I format my results to show the digits after the decimal point

Tags: java, number-formatting

I need a line of code that I can use to get the digits after the decimal place when I execute 
the code below:

```
double results = 1500 / 1000;


        txtview.setText("K " + resultsoldk);
```

I need the results to include the reminder as well.

Comment: what is resultsoldk ? you are getting  devision result in results but in textView you are using resultsoldk ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format Float to n decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195837/format-float-to-n-decimal-places)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the result of

```
 double results = 1500 / 1000;
```

is `1.0`, not `1.5`, because you are doing **integer division**. Make sure at least one of the numbers is a floating-point number when you do the division. For example:

```
// By adding .0 you make it a double literal instead of an int literal
double results = 1500.0 / 1000;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cast using double like below

```
  double results = (double)1500 / 1000;
```

Also you can format the result using DecimalFormat

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00##");
String formattedResult=df.format(results);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [String.format(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method to format the String like this:

```
txtview.setText(String.format("K %f", resultsoldk));
```

However, this will not work in you case. As you are dividing two integers, the result will be an integer (which has no remainder). Afterwards it is converted to a double (because you assign it to a double) but at this point, the precision is already lost. You must at least convert one of the integers to a double *before* you divide them:

```
double results = (double)1500 / 1000;
```

or, if you use constants

```
double results = 1500.0 / 1000;
```

or

```
double results = 1500 / 1000.0;
```

or even

```
double results = 1500.0 / 1000.0;
```

Comment: This is not how you use String.format. The correct way is `String.format("K %f", resultsoldk)` I know it's silly, but that's how they designed this method at Sun.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I program a lot in Python to I'm sometimes a little confused ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
String strResult = Double.toString(d);
strResult = strResult.replaceAll("\\d?\\.", "");
```

Don't know if I get it, but if what you want is the digits after the dot, then you can use this regex.