# Difficulty with some debugging of a code that calculates the discount you would get with various membership levels

Tags: java, debugging, printf

Over all, this code is supposed to ask for the customers name, member level, and original purchase price. It should store all of those in their respective variables, if something other than an accepted member level is entered the program is supposed to exit. After all the variables are stored, the customer's name, member level, original purchase price, promotional price, and amount saved should be printed out in the format at the end of this post. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
import java.util.*;
public class Discount{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    double purchase = 0.0;
    double platinum = (purchase * .2);
    double gold = (purchase * .15);
    double silver = (purchase * .1);
    String Platinum = null;
    String Gold = null;
    String Silver = null;
    String customerName = null;
    String level = null;
    double discount = 0.0;

    System.out.print("Please enter a customer name: ");
    customerName = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Please enter the customer's member level: ");
    level = keyboard.nextLine();

    if (!level.equals("Platinum") && !level.equals("Gold") && !level.equals("Silver"))
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    System.out.print("Please enter the origianl purchase price: ");
    purchase = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Congratualations, " + customerName + "!");

    if (level.equals("Platinum") && purchase > 500)
    {
        discount = (platinum + (purchase*.05));
        System.out.println("As a " + level + " level cardholder, you have received a 25% discount during Bedlam.");
    }
    else if (level.equals("Platinum"))
    {
        discount = (platinum);
        System.out.println("As a " + level + " level cardholder, you have received a 20% discount during Bedlam.");
    }
    else if (level.equals("Gold"))
    {
        discount = (gold);
        System.out.println("As a " + level + " level cardholder, you have received a 15% discount during Bedlam.");
    }
    else if (level.equals("Silver"))
    {
        discount = (silver);
        System.out.println("As a " + level + " level cardholder, you have received a 10% discount during Bedlam.");
    }
```

Everything works fine up until this point, if I put in M as customerName, Silver as level, and 500.20 as purchase this is what prints out in the command prompt:
`Congratualations, M!
As a Silver level cardholder, you have received a 10% discount during Bedlam.
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.PrintStream.format(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.PrintStream.printf(Unknown Source)
        at Discount.main(Discount.java:62)`

```
    System.out.printf("%.2f\n", "Original purchase price: $" + purchase);
    System.out.printf("%.2f\n", "Promotional price: $" + discount);
    System.out.printf("%.2f\n", "Amount saved: $" + (purchase-discount));
```

This is what it should look like if successfully executed:

```
Congratulations, Marge Simpson!
As a Silver level cardholder, you received a 10% discount during Bedlam.
Original purchase price: $500.20
Promotional price: $450.18
Amount saved: $50.02 */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195837/format-float-to-n-decimal-places).
Try this syntax:

```
System.out.println( "Original purchase price: $" + String.format("%.2f",purchase));
System.out.println("Promotional price: $" + String.format("%.2f",discount));
System.out.println("Amount saved: $" + String.format("%.2f", purchase-discount));
```

Comment: That worked, except it's not reading anything into the discount variable. Any suggestions?

Comment: Everything is getting initialized to 0 here:
    double purchase = 0.0;
    double platinum = (purchase * .2);
    double gold = (purchase * .15);
    double silver = (purchase * .1);
Instead of which, you should multiply each variable by `purchase` after `purchase` is set to a non-zero value

Comment: @TreyJonn: since this is likely a homework assignment, in the future please give hints like I did in my comment, instead of giving away the answer. I know I always learned a lot more when I had to struggle through a problem with little or no help.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're basically passing the entire string `"Original purchase price: $" + purchase` as the argument for `%.2f`. Use `String.format` instead:

```
System.out.println("Original purchase price: $" + String.format("%.2f", purchase));
```

That also eliminates the need to append `"\n"` to the string, since you can use `System.out.println`.

Comment: That worked, except it's not reading anything into the discount variable. Any suggestions?

Comment: By "not reading anything into the discount variable", you mean it's set to 0, correct? Look at your code carefully and you'll see why. (Hint: look at the five places where `discount` is on the left side of the equals sign. Notice anything about the values on the right side?)