# ListView that shows numbers with a total at the bottom

Tags: android-listview, android, android-tablelayout

I have a `ListView` in which I show some details including prices.
I need to show the total sum at the bottom of the `ListView`.
So far I've tried with a `ListView` to show the details and a table layout with a single row to show the total, the problem is that I can't get them to be aligned.

Do you know I can get a result like this one:

[image]

I know that the amount for "**Cache**" isn't the **Total**, but the idea is the same. All these rows show their amounts properly aligned and the space between the labels and the amount are filled with dots and this is the result I'd like to achieve, so I would be very grateful if you could help.

### This is the layout I'm currently using for my activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout       
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"        
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/detailsListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"             
        android:stretchColumns="0,1" >
        <TableRow android:padding="1dp" >

            <TextView
                style="@style/Control.Label.Large.Stretched"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/total" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/totalSumTextView"
                style="@style/Control.TextView.Large.Stretched"                
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow3" />
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

### An this is the layout for each item in the ListView :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1" >

        <TableRow android:padding="1dp" >

            <TextView
                style="@style/Control.Label.Small.Stretched"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/item_quantity" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/itemQuantityTextView"
                style="@style/Control.TextView.Small.Stretched"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:padding="1dp" >

            <TextView
                style="@style/Control.Label.Small.Stretched"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/item_unit_price" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/itemUnitPriceTextView"
                style="@style/Control.TextView.Small.Stretched"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </TableRow>        

        <TableRow android:padding="1dp" >

            <TextView
                style="@style/Control.Label.Small.Stretched"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/item_total" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/itemTotalTextView"
                style="@style/Control.TextView.Small.Stretched"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Each Item should look something like this :

[image]

And it's the sum of those totals that should be displayed below the ListView

This image is from what I'm trying to do. It's in Spanish, but it should give you a better picture of what I'm saying. As you can see the row below the ListView is not aligned with the values in the above it.

[image]

Comment: Pass your "Total" title and "total value" as a last element in adapter of list view.

Comment: Add a footer view that uses the same layout as your ListView cells.

Comment: @Chitrang that wouldn't work, because I want the **Total** row to be always visible

Comment: @dcharms how can I add a footer?

Comment: If you want the total to always be visible, a footer is not the way to go. You will need to add a view below the ListView that contains a TextView with the same right margin as the rows in your ListView.

Comment: OK. I'll do that,but just to give you better idea each item in my ListView is similar to the "storage" item in the image I posted.

Comment: Edited my question, please take a look

Comment: You're right. The sum of Totals (`totalSumTextView`) is not aligned with the Totals from the ListView (`itemTotalTextView`). I'll post an image to give you a better idea.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier I've added an image of what I've done so far. I'm still trying to understand why this isn't working.

Comment: @Axel updated answer to show how I would be doing this. Sorry can't get the dots to work, but I normally just use the method similar to Arian's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see these problems in your screenshot:

1. alignment of the columns themselves is different
2. alignment of text in the columns is centred, not right-aligned
3. you probably want to use a fixed number of decimal points in your numeric output
4. row of dots

### 1) Alignment of columns

I think this is to do with using the `TableLayout`. As you can see in my previous example, I prefer to use `RelativeLayout`. When you get the hang of it you will see it is very powerful.

I would use my example below as a starting point for a single row, and make 2 more similar rows below that using the `layout_below` tag to position them below the row above.

Like this (long) example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp" >

    <!-- ROW 1 -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLabel1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Cantidad Pedida" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSizeMb1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tvLabel1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="12.0" />

    <!-- ROW 2 -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLabel2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvLabel1"
        android:text="Unidad Medida" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSizeMb2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tvLabel2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="CJA" />

    <!-- ROW 3 -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLabel3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvLabel2"
        android:text="Precio Unitario" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSizeMb3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tvLabel3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="157.6036" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

### 2) Right-align the text within the columns

Your `TextView` items are being centred in the columns, due to using the `layout_weight="1"` tag. If you instead use the `RelativeLayout` as described above, the text views themselves are being set to the right.

### 3) Fixed format for your decimal numbers

To correctly align numbers, it helps to use a fixed number of decimal points. In your case it looks like you might need 4 decimal places.

When you set the values, you are probably doing something like:

```
myTextView.setText(String.valueOf(myNumber);
```

Instead of that, use the `String.format()` method to set the number of decimal places:

```
myTextView.setText(String.format("%.4f", myNumber);
```

For more info on that, check out this post:

- [Format Float to n decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5383201/383414)

### 4) Row of dots between text fields

I was hoping to get something working with an XML Drawable that uses the `stroke` style, but ran into some strange issues. You might want to play around with that concept a bit.

However what I've done many times in the past is similar to what ArianJM recommends.

```
<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="1px"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tvLabel1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvSizeMb1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvLabel1"
    android:background="#333"
    tools:ignore="PxUsage" />
```

Note the use of `px` instead of `dp` for the height attribute. This creates a sharper image, and by using a `1px` value, the line is not very strong. You could improve this by using a slightly transparent colour for the line.

---

### Previous answer

You could use a basic `ListView` to display your items. The list view can use a custom XML layout for each item, that aligns the text the way you want it to.

For example, here is a `RelativeLayout` that aligns 2 text fields in the way you want them to be aligned:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Total" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSizeMb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="4.57MB" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

Then below your list view, you would want to display your "Cache" row. Use the same layout for this, and the items will align correctly.

Comment: What about the lines between the labels and the TextViews ?

Comment: I didn't mentioned anything about divider, but I did mention the lines(or dots) between the `Labels` and the `TextViews`. I'd be really nice if I could do display something like `"Total ......... $ 250"`

Comment: Thank you guys! I really wished I could mark all three answers because all of them help, but since the answer provided by @Richard was the most complete, I decided to mark it as the answer

Answer (score 2):

I think that for what you want to do you should make a custom layout for your `ListView`, and in that layout make a `TextView` element aligned to the right.

Your XML would contain something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="14.99$" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

That `TextView` is aligned to the right, add anything you want, then use the layout for every element in the `ListView`, all the `TextViews` should then be aligned.

The `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` attribute makes the `TextView` (or any view with that attribute) be aligned to the right (inside it's parent).

**Edit**

For the dots you could use something like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10282253/3290971

The full layout file would be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Item"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/price"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/price"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="14.99$"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The result would be:

[image: Layout result of the previous XML]

Not really dots, but that's something to start from, hope that helps.

Comment: What about the lines between the labels and the TextViews ?

Comment: @eddy I edited my answer to show how to add a line separating the elements.

Answer (score 1):

@axel this is what I did to get a dotted line :

Create a xml file in the drawable folder and named `dotted.xml`. Copy and paste the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line" >
    <stroke
        android:dashGap="3dp"
        android:dashWidth="3dp"
        android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
</shape>
```

and in your layout call the shape using the `background` attribute

```
 <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/price"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/price"
        android:background="@drawable/dotted" />
```

In case the above code doesn't show the dotted line, add this to the `View` :

```
android:layerType="software"
```

Hope it helps