# How to limit a float to give one or no value after the decimal

Tags: eclipse

I'm working in Eclipse and using float for my variables and values. The only issue I am getting is the huge number of digits (1.563524354) after the decimal. Can I somehow limit them to one digit after the decimal like (1.5) or no digit or decimal at all simply like 1. ?

My code:

```
float nCurrentSpeed;
    private long startTime;
    private int count;
    private int pointAverage;
    private Float nMaxSpeed = 0F;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

        this.onLocationChanged(null);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView tvd = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);

        if (location == null) {
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            count = 0;
            pointAverage = 0;

            actualizeTextField();

            tv.setText("0.0");
        } else {

            nCurrentSpeed = location.getSpeed();
            tv.setText(nCurrentSpeed + "");
            count += 1;
            pointAverage += location.getSpeed();
            actualizeTextField();

            if (nMaxSpeed < nCurrentSpeed) {
                nMaxSpeed = nCurrentSpeed;
            }

        }
        tvd.setText(nMaxSpeed.toString());
    }

    private void actualizeTextField() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView tf = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        if (count > 0) {
            long timeOver = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            tf.setText(String.valueOf(pointAverage / (timeOver / 1000)));
        } else {
            tf.setText("0.0");
        }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format Float to n decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195837/format-float-to-n-decimal-places)

Answer (score 0):

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
df.format(0.91231);
```

returns:

```
0.9
```

If you don't want decimal places, why don't you cast it to `int` then?

Comment: It says, "Type mismatch: cannot convert from float to int"

Comment: Use `Math.round()`, returns nearest whole `int`

Comment: Your edit is just a bunch of code, I don't know what are you trying to achieve. Not to sound rude, but Stack is not site where people write code for you.

Comment: you dont need to telme what stack is, if you dont want to contribute than DONT

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

double d = 1.234567;

DecimalFormat df1 = new DecimalFormat("#.##");   // set your format

System.out.print(df1.format(d))

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need point values, why are you using float? Check this one.

```
float nCurrentSpeed;
private long startTime;
private int count;
private int pointAverage;
private int nMaxSpeed = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

    this.onLocationChanged(null);

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView tvd = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);

    if (location == null) {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        count = 0;
        pointAverage = 0;

        actualizeTextField();

        tv.setText("0.0");
    } else {

        nCurrentSpeed = location.getSpeed();
        tv.setText(nCurrentSpeed + "");
        count += 1;
        pointAverage += location.getSpeed();
        actualizeTextField();

        if (nMaxSpeed < nCurrentSpeed) {
            nMaxSpeed = (int)nCurrentSpeed;
        }

    }
    tvd.setText(String.valueOf(nMaxSpeed));
}

private void actualizeTextField() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TextView tf = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    if (count > 0) {
        long timeOver = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        tf.setText(String.valueOf(pointAverage / (timeOver / 1000)));
    } else {
        tf.setText("0.0");
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot invoke toString() on the primitive type int

Comment: See edit. Are you expecting for the whole code ? You have got your answer. And you should accept the answer.

Comment: bro i dont expect the whole code, i am just sharing the error with you.

Comment: If my post is helpful to you. You should accept the answer.