# Java Override toString for multiple member variables

Tags: java, tostring

I have the following class

```
public class Foo {
   private long var1;
   private float var2;
   private double var3;
   /* getter and setter

    */
}
```

To print a numeric value to command line, I use String.valueOf(obj.getVar2()), but this will result in 9.888888888.
Are there any ways, to produce formatted outputs for all numeric getters (float, double)?
I have a function 'bar' , which will format a given numeric value to a string. Now, I want to call functions like obj.getVar2().toString(), to get the numeric value back as a formatted string from 'bar'.
Is it possible?

Comment: "*Now, I want to call functions like `obj.getVar2().toString()`, to get the numeric value back as a formatted string from `bar`. Is it possible?*" do you get any errors when you try it?

Comment: Yes, there are ways and it is possible.

Comment: Refer [format-float-to-n-decimal-places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195837/format-float-to-n-decimal-places)

Comment: I think you should initiate a float/double OBJECT instead of the primitive ones in your getter(), from there you can do obj.getVar2().toString().

Comment: @ MadhanThat the function. Thanks ;)
@ Ramin Omrani Possible, but Long.toString() doesn't support my formatted string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If bar is non-static method - `obj.bar(obj.getVar2());`
If bar is static method - `Foo.bar(obj.getVar2());`

By the way your class definition is wrong. It should be `public class Foo {` not `public class Foo() {`

Comment: This was my first solution. As BladeCoder already said, 'categories' aren't available in Java, so your solution works best in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can add methods to your Foo class:

```
public String getVar1AsString() {
    return Utils.bar(var1);
}
```

But you can not change the semantics of `Float.toString()` or `Double.toString()` to use `bar` internally.

An alternative would be to provide your own `CustomFloat` or `CustomDouble` classes and use them everywhere in your app.

Comment: I had this idea too, but I don't want to have X string-getters for x numeric values. Okay, I could place the formatted function inside my class and call toFormattedString(getVar1()).... I would prefer a simple prefix (like toString()), to get a string value.

Comment: I understand, but Java does not support "extension methods", also called "categories" in objective C.

Comment: Thank you, that's I want to know.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to get formatted numbers:

```
class Foo {
    private long var1;
    private float var2;
    private double var3;

    public double getVar3() { return var3; }
    public float getVar2() { return var2; }
    public long getVar1() { return var1; }

    public String getFormatVar3() {
        // third way
        return String.format("%XXX", var3);
        // or
        return this.bar(var3);
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // first way
        return String.format("%XXX %XXX %XXX", var1, var2, var3);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // second way
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        String format = String.format("%XXX", foo.getVar1());
    }

    private String bar(Number n) {
        // discover type of number
        return String.format("%XXX", n);
    }
}
```

where, `%XXX` is your format.