# SQL I have to display the digits 123.34 as 123.3400000000000 ie., 13 digit after the decimal point without loosing any values

Tags: sql, squirrel-sql

Running query from Java code no chance to change the global preferences. I have to print `123.34` as `123.3400000000000` ie. with 13 digits after the decimal point without losing any values

```
CAST(SUM(F.TOTAL_DOCUMENT_CHARS) AS DECIMAL(18,0))/1000 AS "DOC CHARS"
```

by changing global preferences to default format getting `14891.4530000000000`, without that as well I need to get

Expected output : 123.3400000000000

Comment: DECIMAL(18,0) ... it means value of 18 numbers and 0 decimal spaces ... in your case i guess you need decimal(18,13) ..

Comment: `CAST(SUM(F.TOTAL_DOCUMENT_CHARS)/1000.0 AS DECIMAL(18,13))`?

Comment: [Check this answer ( if it is java )...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195837/format-float-to-n-decimal-places)

Answer (score 0):

declare the variable as decimal(5,13) if you desire the length to remain as 18.