# How to use Floating Point with JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, floating-point

I have a small program to do and i am stuck with floating point.
I want the result to be in 1 dicimle only.

this is my program

[image]

I want to make a floating point in both results whether i convert from F to C or C to F.

i am using JFrame, and i tried to use `String.format` but i doesn't work!

```
 private void cTFActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    float tempFahr = (float) ((Float.parseFloat(cTF.getText()))
            * 1.8 + 32);
    fTF.setText(tempFahr + "");
    String.format("%.1", tTF.getText());
```

The program is working fine, but i had a problem with the dicimles only.

Can you explain to me how to use it with JFrame ?

---

## Edit:

we found the solution already

Comment: Solution to what? Please keep your original question so that others can benefit from it as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the formatted value to the text field, your formatting is basically a no-op. Store the formatted value in the text field:

```
fTF.setText(format(tempFahr));
```

Replace `format` with [anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195837/format-float-to-n-decimal-places) you choose for formatting.

Comment: And in that case concatenating the empty string should become unnecessary :)

Comment: @Thomas True, I copy-pasted it from the OP question. Edited, thanks.

Comment: JFormattedTextField with number formatter, with mix/max decimal places

Comment: Thank you guys , that's was very helpful. :)