# Java decimal point given by user

Tags: java

How to printf decimal point by user?
For example:

float a = 122.32445;

int decimal = 2;

And I want to print 122.32
I know that exist:

```
System.out.printf("%.2f", a);
```

But how to implement that decimal point there? I came up with something like this:

```
System.out.printf("%.%df, decimal, a);
```

But it of course it doesn't work. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format Float to n decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195837/format-float-to-n-decimal-places)

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.printf("%." + decimal + "f", a);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("##,##0.00");
```

does the trick.