# Precision when Casting from Double to Float while concatenating String?

Tags: java, casting, double, precision

I recently ran in the following curiosity:

```
    double d=0.8608278036117554;
    String precision="float";

    float f=(float)d;
    String s="a " + (precision.equals("float") ? (float)d: d) + " Bonjour";
    String s2="a " + String.valueOf(precision.equals("float") ? (float)d: d) + " Bonjour";
    String s3="a " + (precision.equals("float") ? String.valueOf((float)d): String.valueOf(d)) + " Bonjour";


    println(d);
    println(f);
    println(s);
    println(s2);
    println(s3);


//0.8608278036117554
//0.8608278
//a 0.8608278036117554 Bonjour
//a 0.8608278036117554 Bonjour
//a 0.8608278 Bonjour
```

Why is it not possible to have a nice float when computing **s** or **s2** ?
Why is it still a double in case **s** and **s2**?

PS: This question has nothing to do with number formatting, in my opinion. I really want to understand why is the **(float)d** cast not working!!

Comment: The result of a `boolean ? float : double` is a `double` It is casting to float but that is being cast back to a double.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression `precision.equals("float") ? (float)d: d` has no effect, as the conditional operator has one single resulting type, which is `double` if one argument has the type `float` and the other has the type `double`.

So the first alternative will be widened from `float` to `double` and while the conversion from `double` to `float` and back to `double` may have an effect on the value, `String.valueOf(double)` will be called in either case.

You can use `(precision.equals("float") ? String.valueOf((float)d): String.valueOf(d))` instead, whose method invocations are not redundant, as they are invocations of different methods, `String.valueOf(float)` and `String.valueOf(double)`.

That said, you should not use narrowing to `float` to control the output.
Check [Format Float to n decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195837/format-float-to-n-decimal-places) for alternatives which provide more control over the formatted output.

Comment: I understand better now. But then if it's cast to a float and back to double, how come the precision is not lost? Shouldn't I have a bunch of zeros at the end instead of the real double decimals?

Comment: The precision of `float` and `double` is defined in terms of *binary* digits, not decimal digits. For some values, this conversion may truncate some non-zero bits (that’s why I said, *may* have an effect on the value), but the resulting value isn’t necessarily a value with less decimal digits.

Comment: Indeed, I have tried the cast back and forth, separately from the whole "String" stuff, I get the same double from the float. So if I understand well, it is really a matter of coincidence that led back to the same double, and had I chosen another example, I could have spotted a change in the digits, right?

Comment: Actually, it was no coincidence since I chose a value from the boggy file that was not correctly transformed to float values :s

Comment: You may use `double d=0.1` for example. Both, `String.valueOf(d)` and `String.valueOf((float)d)` will produce `"0.1"`, but `String.valueOf((double)(float)d)` will produce `"0.10000000149011612"`.