# float, round to 2 decimal places - Processing

Tags: processing, number-formatting

I started learning processing since a short time ago and I came across a problem; When deviding 199.999 by 200 **I want to outcome to be with 2 decimals** (so the outcome should be 1 rounded of). Without formatting  the outcome is 0.999995.

**Code for formatting to String with 2 decimal:**

```
float money = 199.999;
int munten = 200;

String calc1 = nf(money/munten,0,2);
println(calc1);

float calc2 = float(calc1);
println(calc2);
```

**Prints:**

```
1,0
NaN
```

I think float() wont work cause there is a comma in the String instead of a dot, I'm not sure tough. But how can I round a number to 2 decimal and still let it be a float?

Thanks for taking your time to read this,

Comment: You say "there is a comma in the String instead of a dot" -- this may be a regional setting. What is the OS and default language of your computer? What version of Processing are you using?

Comment: which language is this?

Comment: I'm using 3.3.6 (Dutch) but that shouldn't change the dot into a comma, never changed any settings..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your example on Processing 3.3.6 / macOS 10.12 (US), I get "1.00" and "1.0". This could be due to your number formatting settings creating output strings that are then not read correctly by `nf()`.

```
float money;
int munten;
String s;
float f;

money = 199.999;
munten = 200;

s = nf(money/munten, 0, 2);
println(s);   // "1.00" -- or "1,0" etc. in different os language locales
f = float(s);
println(f);   // "1.0" -- or NaN error if above is not 1.0 format

f = money/munten;
println(f);   // 0.999995
s = nf(f, 0, 2);
println(s);   // 1.00 -- or local format
```

You can see what should be happening more clearly in the second bit of code -- don't try to convert into a String and then back out again; don't store numbers in Strings. Instead, keep everything in numeric variables up until the moment you need to display.

Also keep in mind that `nf()` isn't really for rounding precision, although it is often used that way:

> nf() is used to add zeros to the left and/or right of a number. This is typically for aligning a list of numbers. To *remove* digits from a floating-point number, use the int(), ceil(), floor(), or round() functions. https://processing.org/reference/nf_.html

If you need to work around your locale, you can use Java String formatting in Processing to do so:

```
float fval = 199.999/200;
println(fval);   // 0.999995
String s = String.format(java.util.Locale.US,"%.2f", fval);
println(s);   // 1.00
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5383201/7207622 for more discussion of the Java approach.

Comment: I'm using Processing 3.3.6, never changed any settings. But on your second print "f = float(s); println(f); //1.0" I still get NaN. Your second peace of code works tough

Comment: Right. "1,0" is NaN (not a number) because nf() reads like eg US English. The comma is probably an **operating system setting** based on your region and language, not a Processing setting. That's why I asked what your OS and language settings are.