# How to round returned value from date.getTime() method

Tags: java, android

I am trying to round the following value `1.48824E9`, that is returning inside the date.getTime() method.

This is what I've tried but It's not working:

```
    private double x;
    private double y;
    DecimalFormat df;
    private double z;
    private String g;
    double a;

    public GraphPoints(Date x, double y) {
        df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
        df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);
        a = x.getTime();
        g = df.format(a);
        z = Double.parseDouble(g);
        System.out.println("THIS IS THE ROUNDED VALUE: " + z);
        this.x = z;

        this.x = z;
        this.y = y;
    }
```

I'm trying to round it to one decimal place. Could someone help me please?

Comment: see this post relevant to you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195837/format-float-to-n-decimal-places

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any decimal places in your number (I mean you have 2 decimal places by default `.00`, but I assume that it is not what you are looking for). `"1.48824E9"` is a scientific notation for the "1488240000.00" double. Consider this code snippet:

```
Double d = Double.parseDouble("1.48824E9");
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
System.out.println(formatter.format(d));

System.out.println(d);
```

Output:

```
1488240000.00
1.48824E9
```

Not sure though how you get it because `date.getTime()` returns long and `Long.toString()` doesn't convert to scientific notation. So, if you want to print `"1.5"` from `"1.48824E9"` you can do it like this for example:

```
Double d = Double.parseDouble("1.48824E9");
d = d / Math.pow(10, 9);
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.0");

System.out.println(formatter.format(d));
```

Output:

```
1.5
```

If you actually want to change the value of your double you can do it this way:

```
Double d = Double.parseDouble("1.48824E9");
d = d / Math.pow(10, 9);
d = Math.round (d * 10.0) / 10.0; 

System.out.println(d);
```

Output:

```
1.5
```

Comment: Hi @Sergei Sirik, this is great, however, when attempting to do this, i get the following value when i rounded it:  1490.9. The value that I'm trying to round is first converted into a string, and then parsed into a double and the rest follows through, but im not getting 1.5.