# How to write double number shorter in java?

Tags: java, number-formatting

I have part of the code:

```
public void CollectorOrPocrushka(double output) {
    if (output <= 0.4999999999999999999999)
        System.out.println("покришка");
    if (output > 0.5 && output <= 1.0)
        System.out.println("колектор");
}
```

Can I write float number `0.4999999999999999999999` shorter?

Something like that:
0.49F
0.49e^10

Comment: Writing it _shorter_ how? Like maybe writing just `0.49` and putting a bar over the `9`? What did you have in mind?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format Float to n decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195837/format-float-to-n-decimal-places)

Comment: I mean, how to make from 0.4999999.... something like that 0.49e^10

Comment: @ Kevin Anderson I mean, how to make from 0.4999999.... something like that 0.49e^10

Comment: You can't use 0.49, because that is not 0.4999999999999999999999, but more like 0.48999999999999999. You can't use 0.49e^10, because that is 4900000000

Comment: @ Mark Rotteveel So what can I use? I need shortform of 0.49999999

Answer (score 3):

If your question is about to simplify the first if condition and your goal is to check if the output is less than or equal 0.4999999999999999999999, you can easily write

```java
if(output < 0.5) 
    System.out.println("покришка");
```

Comment: I mean, how to make from 0.4999999.... something like that 0.49e^10 @AmrDeveloper